# create function visual studio 2010 with optional parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

in Visual Studio 2010 I can do this:

```
  public static void setString(string x = "asd"){  }
```

But in VS 2008 marks an error,

I'm using framework 3.5

how can I solve it or what can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was [introduced in VS 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx).

However, you can get much the same effect with an overload:

```
public static void setString()
{
    setString("asd");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Optional parameters (what you are doing) were introduced in Visual Studio 2010.  It won't work for C# in VS 2008.  Please see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx

To make your current code work in VS 2008, you'd have to remove the optional parameter.

```
public static void setString(string x){  }

setString("asd");
```

Comment: thank you, any way i can do a hax to simulate my desired result?

Comment: Minor issue with your answer, but optional parameters are not explicitly `.Net 4.0`, they are specific to Visual Studio 2010 or greater, regardless of the Framework version you are targeting.  I can use optional parameters in C#3 as long as I am using VS2010.

Comment: Excellent point and I'll update my answer to reflect such.  This answers your question Gaddiel.  You could use VS 2010 targeting 3.5.  Other than that however, I have not seen a hack that works around it.